# generating images with imagejpeg in PHP

Tags: php, image

I don't know where I've got a mistake, when I fire below code from `http://localhost/image.php?application=first` everything is OK.

```
session_start();
$name = $_GET['application'];   

$text = rand(10000,99999); 
$_SESSION['application'][$name] = $text;

$height = 25; 
$width = 65; 
$image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
$black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
$white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
$font_size = 14; 

imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
```

but when I changed code for this

```
if (isset($_GET['application']) && !empty($_GET['application'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['image']) && $_GET['image'] == 'get'){
    session_start();
    $name = $_GET['application'];   

    $text = rand(10000,99999); 
    $_SESSION['application'][$name] = $text;

    $height = 25; 
    $width = 65; 
    $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
    $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
    $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
    $font_size = 14;
    imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 

    imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
}
}
```

then I get RAW format in browser, so I add

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
```

to the code, and now I've get message, that my picture is interrupted, but when I save it on drive and launch from IrfanView it opens normally.

I would like to add that I was testing `ob_start()` function, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: do you pass the correct GET parameters to your script ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I figure it out. the problem was that I add `require 'common.php'` before main IF statment. My whole code were like this

```
<?php
require 'common.php';
    if (isset($_GET['application']) && !empty($_GET['application'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['image']) && $_GET['image'] == 'get'){
        session_start();
        $name = $_GET['application'];                   $text = rand(10000,99999);             $_SESSION['application'][$name] = $text;
            $height = 25;             $width = 65;             $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height);             $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);             $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255);             $font_size = 14;
        imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white);                 header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
    }
.
.
.
```

so when i moved require to other place everythig works great!
Thanks mates for help! :)

Answer (score 2):

Works great for me when I hit this URL:

```
http://localhost/image.php?application=first&image=get
```

Here is the exact code I am using in image.php:

```
if (isset($_GET['application']) && !empty($_GET['application'])) {
    if (isset($_GET['image']) && $_GET['image'] == 'get'){
        session_start();
        $name = $_GET['application'];   

        $text = rand(10000,99999); 
        $_SESSION['application'][$name] = $text;

        $height = 25; 
        $width = 65; 
        $image_p = imagecreate($width, $height); 
        $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0); 
        $white = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 255, 255, 255); 
        $font_size = 14;
        imagestring($image_p, $font_size, 5, 5, $text, $white); 

        header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
        imagejpeg($image_p, null, 80);
    }
}

?>
```